# How to partition my Hard Disk to facilitate installation?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I am new to Linux family and willing to install ubuntu 11.10 x86 (32 bit) alongside Windows 7, i.e., Dual-Boot. I have searched a lot about how to make partitions of my hard disk for installing ubuntu but everyone follows a different rule or scheme which is making me a bit confused. So i am seeking help on how to install ubuntu alongside Windows 7.

This is my Laptop's Configuration:
Lenovo Thinkpad - B560
Processor - i3 (570M)
HDD - 500 gb
RAM - 4 gb
Intel 1 gb graphics

and my partitions at this point is like:

```
Volume:     File System:     Status:     Capacity:     Free Space:

(C:)          NTFS           Primary     48.73 gb         30.36 gb
(H:)          NTFS           Logical     55.60 gb         55.51 gb
(G:)          NTFS           Logical     68.36 gb         60.14 gb
(E:)          NTFS           Logical     97.65 gb         93.53 gb
(F:)          NTFS           Logical     97.65 gb         96.00 gb
(D:)          NTFS           Logical     97.65 gb         95.28 gb
System        NTFS           Primary     100.00 mb        72.00 mb
```

Now when i am trying to make a primary root partition using the H:\ drive of mine, of about 20 gb, then the remaining 35 gb is showing as unusable.

Please help me on this on how to make partitions for root directory of 20 gb, swap partition 5 gb and a home directory of the remaining space...

So will i install Ubuntu root drive by making Primary partition or in logical partition?

Comment: In which partition do you have Windows 7 installed?  Are you attempting to make your partition from within Windows, or from the Ubuntu installation disk?

Comment: I have Windows 7 installed in the C: partition. I am attempting to install Ubuntu from installation disk for dual-booting windows 7 and Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Open Up G-Parted after booting.

Edit the partition as required...

```
Create ur 20 Gb for /
5 gb for swap
Create ur Home Partition for wat ever size u want
```

apply

there you are done

start installtion mount the appropriate points and install...

**TIPS:**

since you are new and as far as i know may be trying it out ignore the creation of a dedicated home mount let it be in root folder, cause trust me its very smooth and most command that you'll find over the course of getting familiar may say like

```
sudo sh /home/<username>/Download/script.sh
```

so it might be easier for you but if u think u gonna be messing a lot and would like to keep individual app settings then do create a partition it will save a lot of time

If u are doubtfull of partitioning in linux , partition ur drive in Windows itself, I would recommend Easeus Partition Magic from [Here](http://www.partition-tool.com/download.htm)
and den boot into ubuntu
no need to format just create partition and leave

Also label your drive in Windows like Win7, Multimedia, Movies etc what ever u think so while formatting the drive name shows up and u dont make a mistake, it will also helo as mount points after installation will be named after the drive label and easy for you to find ur files.
Also you might wanna use Unetbootin Tool to make a bootable USB drive for ubuntu installation and den boot off the USB [create atlest 512 mb of presistence]

Speeds up the process as CD/DVD read speeds on laptop are very slow and often due to this makes the LIVE System unresponsive.